# WCF service prompting for credentials without ComponentModel.Container

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services, system.componentmodel

I'm learning how to work with WCF for a project at work, so I'm trying to set up a service based on the code of a previous project. Although I succeeded, whenever I try to install the executable (with installutil) it prompts me for credentials. After some inspection I noticed this happens because the `InitializeComponent` method is set as such (as per the auto-generated code):

```
this.serviceProcessInstaller1 = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller();
this.serviceInstaller1 = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller();
// 
// serviceProcessInstaller1
// 
this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Password = null;
this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Username = null;
// 
// serviceInstaller1
// 
this.serviceInstaller1.ServiceName = "XYZService";
// 
// ProjectInstaller
// 
this.Installers.AddRange(new System.Configuration.Install.Installer[] {
this.serviceProcessInstaller1,
this.serviceInstaller1});
```

While the project I'm basing it on replaces all those lines with `components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();`, and it works, it's not asking for credentials anymore.

Could someone explain why this is the case, though? My manager told me he did this change specifically to avoid credential prompts, but didn't explain *why* that line of code does the trick.

In case it's relevant, the `ProjectInstaller` method has been modified to this:

```
InitializeComponent();
ServiceProcessInstaller serviceProcessInstaller = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
ServiceInstaller serviceInstaller = new ServiceInstaller();

//# Service Account Information

serviceProcessInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
serviceProcessInstaller.Username = null;
serviceProcessInstaller.Password = null;

//# Service Information

serviceInstaller.DisplayName = "XYZ Server";
serviceInstaller.Description = "This service initializes the XYZ Server";
serviceInstaller.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic;

//# This must be identical to the WindowsService.ServiceBase name

//# set in the constructor of WindowsService.cs

serviceInstaller.ServiceName = XYZService._serviceName;

this.Installers.Add(serviceProcessInstaller);
this.Installers.Add(serviceInstaller);
```

Comment: The binding (or WCF in general) shouldn't affect the credentials needed to install. Sounds like the problem is with the installer.

Comment: How can the code that governs the security mode be called if the program isn't installed yet?